# Unable to refresh listview after fetching Json

Tags: android, dart, flutter, flutter-layout, dart-html

I have been trying to fetch data from server and display it in listview.builder inside futurebuilder but the listview is only updated after applying setstate() ,please help have been stucked for a while.

```
  Future<dynamic> _fetchData() async {
    sPref.getUserId().then((onValue) {
      userIds = onValue;
    });
    sPref.getAuthToken().then((val) {
      token = val;
      var body = {
        'userId': '$userIds',
      };
      var client = http.Client();    

      var response = http.Request(
          'POST', Uri.parse('http://example.net/api/fetchJson'));    

      response.headers["Authorization"] = "Bearer $token";
      response.bodyFields = body;
      print(response.headers);
      client.send(response).then((response) {
        return http.Response.fromStream(response);
      }).then((res) {
        return res.body;
      }).then((body) {
        return json.decode(body);
      }).then((body) {
        print(body.toString());
        var datas = body['data'];
        if (body['status'] == 'success') {
          list = (datas as List)
              .map((data) => new PosModelData.fromJson(data))
              .toList();
          return list;
        } else {
          print('failed');
        }
      });
      return list;
    });
  }
```

This is where i am calling it in future.Need to know where i am going wrong.

```
           body: FutureBuilder(
             future: _fetchData(),
             builder: (context, data) {
               switch (data.connectionState) {
                 case ConnectionState.none:
                 case ConnectionState.waiting:
                   return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                 default:
                   // if (data.hasError)
                   //   return new Text('Error: ${data.error}');
                   // else
                   return ListView.builder(
                     itemCount: list.length,
                     itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                       return Container(
                         padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                             horizontal: 6.0, vertical: 4.0),
                         child: Card(
                           elevation: 10.0,
                           child: Column(children: <Widget>[
                             ListTile(
                               title: Text(list[index].firstName),
                               subtitle: list[index].phone != null
                                   ? Text(list[index].phone)
                                   : Text('Not mentioned'),
                               trailing: trailingText(index),
                             ),
                           ]),
                         ),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code you didn't call `return` from your `_fetchData()` block.

Your return type is `Future`, you need to use `await`, specify your return type `List<PosModelData>` and `return` from your `async` block

```
Future<List<PosModelData>> _fetchData() async {
  final response = await http.Request('POST', Uri.parse('http://example.net/api/fetchJson')); 
  final list = ... convert response to list
  return list;
}
```

Then you will get list from callback `builder: (context, data) {}`.

Please check [this](https://flutter.io/cookbook/networking/fetch-data/) example.

**Updated 1**

Instead of using `async` and `await`, another way to use `Future` is by returning `Future` type. Specify your return type `Future<List< PosModelData>>` and return `Future` type

`return sPref.then((s) {}`.

Please check the following sample codes and `Futures` [document](https://www.dartlang.org/tutorials/language/futures) for dart asynchronous programming.

```
Future<List<PosModelData>> _fetchData() {
  return Future.wait([sPref.getUserId(), sPref.getAuthToken()]).then((data) {
    userIds = data.first;
    token = data[1];

    var body = {
      'userId': '$userIds',
    };
    var client = http.Client();

    var response = http.Request(
        'POST', Uri.parse('http://example.net/api/fetchJson'));

    response.headers["Authorization"] = "Bearer $token";
    response.bodyFields = body;
    print(response.headers);
    return client.send(response).then((response) {
      return http.Response.fromStream(response);
    }).then((res) {
      return res.body;
    }).then((body) {
      return json.decode(body);
    }).then((body) {
      print(body.toString());
      var datas = body['data'];
      if (body['status'] == 'success') {
        list = (datas as List)
            .map((data) => new PosModelData.fromJson(data))
            .toList();
        return list;
      } else {
        print('failed');
      }
    });
  });
```

Comment: i tried adding implementing await bt inside sPref.getAuthtoken is not working.

Comment: this might work , but sPref or the instance of sharedPreference does not have ".then" method

Comment: please check updated part. You can use `Future.wait` for combining those instance has `.then` method like  `sPref.getUserId()` and `sPref.getAuthToken()`

Comment: awesome bro thanx , it worked and i learned something new : )